# Why is the To property of .net's MailMessage class read-only?

Tags: c#, email

I've got a MailAddressCollection that contains all the addresses I want to send an email to, but instead of being able to simply have:

```
myMessage.To = myMailAddressCollection;
```

I have to do:

```
foreach (MailAddress address in myMailAddressCollection)  
{  
    myMessage.To.Add(address);  
}
```

Can anyone shed any light on why the class is configured like that? Am I missing some other way of being able to assign to the To, CC or Bcc properties?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The MailMessage class wants to protect it's properties, that's proper Encapsulation.

Your task would have been a little easier if it had supported a AddRange method but as it stands your code is about as easy as it's going to get.

Comment: Yeah, AddRange would have been ideal... oh well, I guess it's not the end of the world!

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but in case someone else stumbles across it:

MailAddressCollection.Add can accept a comma delimited string of email addresses.  MailAddressCollection.ToString Method returns a comma delimited string of the contained email addresses.

So the OP could have done this:

```
myMessage.To.Add(myMailAddressCollection.ToString());
```

An AddRange method would still be preferred.